# Is there a fast command like tar --remove-files that leaves file chunks in place?

Tags: directory, tar, move

I create hundreds of thousands of files, each several megabytes, resulting in directories (and subdirectories) containing a TB or more.  To move the data to another drive, 'cp' tends to slow down over time.  rsync does a decent job, but it's hard to monitor copying progress.  Compressing it does little (already compressed files) and takes -forever-.  'tar' does a sortof quick job of combining it all into one file, and makes copying it faster/easier, but it requires the same amount of space again on the drive (which is often already nearly full).

Is there anything on ext4 filesystem which allows to quickly combine many files into one file, without actually moving the source files' data?   Kinda like 'mv' in the same file system, it doesnt actually copy and delete the data, it just charges the file path.

Comment: The best is `mv` command. This do not use additional space, normally it copy the file and then remove it.

Comment: Are you making a tar file, then copying it over, and then untarring it? Why not `tar c -C /source/path . | tar x -C /dest/path`?

Comment: @muru, will be wise to use form like `tar tf - sources| tar xf - -C /destination` This will make it a bit more portable :)

Comment: I tend towards `( cd source && tar cf - . ) | ( cd dest && tar xf - )`, especially where I need to run the second tar within ssh.

Comment: Thanks folks.  I dont feel you've answered the core question (in-place archiving), but it does seem like there are better options for my particular need.  Probably it's best for me to tar to a destination on the transport drive.  That way it doesnt take space on the source drive, and the data transfer is seamlessly part of the tar process.